# How can I get the CKEditor Inline Toolbar to fade in and out?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm currently using CKEditor in a webapp that I am building. I'd like to have the Inline Toolbar fade in when the text box is focused and fade out when unfocused. I'd normally just add a transition for this but the toolbar seems to be shown/hidden with the Visibility attribute added via a JS file which causes problems.

Does anyone have a good solution for fading the toolbar in and out?

**EDIT Adding startup code as requested**:

In my HTML I have a div which looks like the following:

`<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>`

And then in mu .JS file I run the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

    //More Code

    CKEDITOR.inline('editor');

    //More Code
}
```

**EDIT 2: Got it half working**
So I've managed to get it fading in by using the 'focus' event trigger like so:

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;
    $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0' });
    editor.on('focus', function () {
        $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0', "transition": "opacity 0.2s linear" });
        setTimeout(function () { $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '1' }) }, 200);
    });
```

However I cannot seem to get it to fade out again as as soon as the Editor is 'blurred' it gets "Display: none" applied to it programmatically.

Comment: can you send the edition version & code of initiation?. also try with ck editor event list? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager

Comment: @PrasadGayan I've updated the post with my initiation code. I'm using CKEditor 4 with the Standard Build. I'll try using the focus/blur functions and report back.

Comment: Here's an idea that might work: you can add a styleclass dynamically on blur event, e.g. *"always-display"*, and in the CSS for this class say something like: *.always-display {display: block !important;
}*. In addition, add a javascript *setTimeout* to remove the class after your blur  duration.

Comment: Is this live somewhere or can you throw together a fiddle?

Comment: @DaniëlCamps Thank you! Your idea worked! I've added an answer and I've added credit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad it works Conor, here is the full anwswer:

By dynamically adding a styleclass on the blur event, e.g. "always-display", the `display: none;`  is overwritten. A javascript `setTimeout` can remove this class after the desired blur duration.

HTML/JavaScript/CSS snippet (not live due to cross-origin frame):

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );


editor.on('focus', function () {
    $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0', "transition": "opacity 0.2s linear" });
    setTimeout(function () { $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '1' }) }, 200);
});

editor.on('blur', function () {
    //force CKEditor to be visible, by overwriting 'display:none'
    $('#cke_editor').addClass("always-display");
    //attach fade effect
    $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0' });
    //remove override forcing visibility after fade effect has taken place
    setTimeout(function () { $('#cke_editor').removeClass("always-display"); }, 200);
});
```

```css
.always-display{
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="editor1" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So thank you to DaniëlCamps and PrasadGayan for their help, with it I managed to create my own solution to the problem.

I added the following Focus and Blur event handlers *after* the Editor is initialised:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

editor.on('focus', function () {
    $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0', "transition": "opacity 0.2s linear" });
    setTimeout(function () { $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '1' }) }, 200);
});

editor.on('blur', function () {
    $('#cke_editor').addClass("always-display");
    $('#cke_editor').css({ 'opacity': '0' });
    setTimeout(function () { $('#cke_editor').removeClass("always-display"); }, 200);
});
```

And the Always-Display class looks like:

```
.always-display{
    display: block !important;
}
```